# Fix a variable to a register in LLVM IR

Tags: c, llvm, x86-64

I'm writing an LLVM pass. For a particular variable I want to use a register (machine dependant register that is). Can I specify this in LLVM IR, so that LLVM backend use that register for the variable and does not use that register for other purposes.

Comment: This is dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897726/use-a-particular-register-for-a-variable-in-llvm/9901873#9901873, btw.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible right now.